# What does the throw keyword mean in C

Tags: c, gcc, keyword, throw

I tried googling it but all results were about C++'s `throw std::exception()`.

I was reading through libraries (was curious how stuff like `printf`, `malloc` and `FILE` were implemented) and came across the definition for the `malloc` function:

```c
extern void *malloc (size_t __size) __THROW __attribute_malloc__
     __attribute_alloc_size__ ((1)) __wur;
```

When using the IDE (Visual Studio Code) to trace back to definitions for each thing, `__THROW` led to this:

```c
# if !defined __cplusplus && __GNUC_PREREQ (3, 3)
   // stuff that doesn't happen
# else
#  if defined __cplusplus && __GNUC_PREREQ (2,8)
#   define __THROW  throw ()
#   define __THROWNL    throw ()
#   define __NTH(fct)   __LEAF_ATTR fct throw ()
#   define __NTHNL(fct) fct throw ()
// continuation to the if-else macro
```

This confused me, as, as far as i know, c doesn't have exceptions and instead uses int error codes. Even more, why are there parentheses as in a function call?

What does it mean and what does it do in the presented case?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything in C, since C doesn't have exceptions.

Comment: `if defined __cplusplus` is only true when it's compiling C++, not C. When GCC is compiling C, the macro expands to nothing.

Comment: add `#define __THROW XXX` to your code, preprocessor will say '__THROW already defined here....` so you can see what is it defeined as

Comment: The point of this is to allow the same header files to work in both C and C++. `__THROW` will expand in C++, but not in C.

Comment: i see, it's on me that i didn't pay close enough attention and got tricked by the ide code highlighting, thanks for clearing things up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `throw` keyword in C. That's a C++ thing.

As to why you find it in your code, the clue is right here in the preprocessor macros:

```c
# if !defined __cplusplus && __GNUC_PREREQ (3, 3)
   // stuff that doesn't happen
# else
#  if defined __cplusplus && __GNUC_PREREQ (2,8)
#   define __THROW  throw ()
#   define __THROWNL    throw ()
#   define __NTH(fct)   __LEAF_ATTR fct throw ()
#   define __NTHNL(fct) fct throw ()
// continuation to the if-else macro
```

This code is written so it will compile with either a C or C++ compiler. The C++ bit that references `throw` and other C++isms will only be compiled if a C++ compiler is used, as such a compiler will define the `__cplusplus` macro.

When you compile it with a C compiler, only the bit marked `// stuff that doesn't happen` will be used, not the else block.

Answer (score 3):

The C 2017 standard doesn't define a `throw` keyword.  The header file may be used by both C and C++ compilers and as @Barmar noted it doesn't apply to C (in C++, btw, `throw()` specifier means that the function doesn't throw exceptions).

Answer (score 2):

There is no `throw` keyword in C. In C, the source text `throw` is an ordinary identifier.

The macro `__THROW` you show is replaced by nothing (an empty sequence of preprocessor tokens) when compiling in C, because the compilers the code you show is targeted for define `__cplusplus` only when compiling as C++, not when compiling as C. So, in C, `!defined __cplusplus_` is true, and the `// stuff that doesn't happen` happens. You do not show that code, but it likely contains `#define __THROW` or equivalent, defining `__THROW` to be replaced by the empty sequence.

If you see other statements being used, where `__THROW` is defined to be replaced by `throw ()`, then you are compiling in C++ mode, not C.